# panda's dataset.column to numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**dataset.columns[attribute_index]**

I don't understand what the line above does, and I can't figure it out how to do the same in NumPy.
Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Is `dataset` a `pandas.DataFrame` object? What is `columns` and `attribute_index`? Try printing them out to see what they have inside. Maybe then we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you said should be "pandas" `DataFrame.columns[index]`
The method to convert `DataFrame.columns` to `numpy array` is:

```
df.columns.to_numpy()
```